# Can i call request A within the test section of request B

Tags: postman

So i have two requests A,B within Postman.

I want to call request A within the test section of request B , request A sets an environmental value in the test section so i want to use it for my validation for the test in request B. Is this possible?

Pre-request script for A:

```
pm.environment.set("R1",pm.request)
```

Pre-request script for B:

```
pm.sendRequest(pm.environment.get("R1"))
```